# Getting 404 error with autolinker

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I've been on this one for a day now and just can't figure it out myself.

So basically I'm trying to use Autolinker.js to automatically make urls into hyperlinks in my chat, but it just gives me a 404 error, so I can't do anything with it.

in my index.php body tag I have:

```
<script src="http://10.11.2.102:8080/dist/Autolinker.js"></script>
```

And In my server.js for nodejs I have,

```
Autolinker = require( 'autolinker' );
```

[image: Just ignore the weird chat]

and I still get this error, I've tried alot of things and I'm still just getting a 404 error. Why can't it find it?

Sorry if this has already been answered, I've tried looking and couldn't find an answer myself.

Comment: You installed it with npm?, try `bower install Autolinker.js --save` and link to it, npm is for backend, and not for frontend.

Comment: Ah, I'll try this and message back if it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem, don't know if it has any consequences though.

Instead of writing a port in it like this

```
<script src="http://10.11.2.102:8080/dist/Autolinker.js"></script>
```

I instead just gave a direct path to the file.

```
<script src="http://10.11.2.102/testsite/node_modules/autolinker/dist/Autolinker.js"></script>
```

And i can now access the file.